# Creating a Photoshop-like button that opens a menu after a long press

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to create a Photoshop-like button, i.e. a button that:

- Has a "default" state. A single click on this button does X.
- A long click/press opens up a dropdown menu. Choosing anything else makes it the (single-click) default.

Here's where I got so far: https://jsfiddle.net/25mc3mtz/2/

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group">
  <a class="btn btn-large" id="myDropdown" href="#" onmousedown="func()" onmouseup="revert()">
    <i class="icon-file">&nbsp;</i>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
  var timer;
  var isTrue = false;

  function func() {
    $("#myDropdown").attr('data-toggle', '');
    $("#myDropdown").removeClass('dropdown-toggle');
    isTrue = true;
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      showDropDown();
    }, 1000);
  }

  function showDropDown() {
    if (timer)
      clearTimeout(timer);

    if (isTrue) {
      $("#myDropdown").attr('data-toggle', 'dropdown');
      $("#myDropdown").addClass('dropdown-toggle');
      $("a .dropdown-toggle").trigger('click');
    }
  }

  function revert() {
    isTrue = false;
  }
</script>
```

I would like to know:

1. Does my solution look right? I feel like it's kinda "dirty"... Any suggestions on how to improve it?
2. How can I make the dropdown show up immediately after a second, rather only after I release the mouse button? I am not sure how I can achieve it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That looks perfectly right... :)